# How to change Django Admin Custom list field label?

Tags: python, django, django-models, label, django-admin

How to change **`my_stock` verbose_name**?

models.py:

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(u"Нэр", max_length=200)
    stock = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def my_stock(self):
        return self.stock
```

admin.py:

```py
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display  = ('name', 'my_stock')
    search_fields = ('name', )
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I guess you should use short_description attribute. [Django-admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

```py
def my_stock(self):
    return self.stock
my_stock.short_description = 'Your label here'
```

Answer (score 5):

change your model and verbose_name parametr to field. I change "author" label to "Author(s)"

models.py

```
class books(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    author= models.CharField(max_length = 250, verbose_name='Author(s)')
```

or simply

```
author      = models.CharField('Author(s)',max_length = 250)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create **the custom column "my_stock"** with `my_stock()` then can rename it with [@admin.display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#the-display-decorator) as shown below:

```py
# "models.py"

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(u"Нэр", max_length=200)
    stock = models.IntegerField()

    # @property
    # def in_stock(self):
    #     return self.stocks.count()
```

```py
# "admin.py"

class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display  = ('name', 'my_stock')
    search_fields = ('name', )
                                     # ↓ Displayed 
    @admin.display(description='Your label here')
    def my_stock(self, obj):
        return obj.stock
```