# change colum name in django admin

Tags: python, django

In django admin site i see the my model field names are short like dob(for Date of birth etc). How can i customize admin page to display custom field name. My model and and admin.py as follows, I searched and found that i have to use short description, but not sure exactly where to use or how to implement it.

```
class Project(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
        description = models.CharField(max_length = 254)

        def __unicode__(self):
             return u"%s" % (self.name)

class Employee(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
     dob = models.DateField()
     doj = models.DateField()
         mobile=models.IntegerField(max_length = 12)
         email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
     bill = models.BooleanField(db_index=True,default=False)
     proj = models.ForeignKey(Project)

        def custom_field_name(self):
          return self.dob
        custom_field_name.short_description = 'Date Of Birth'

     def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % (self.name)
```

admin.py as follows,

```
 class EmployeeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name']
        list_display = ('name','bill','mobile','email')
        list_filter = ('bill','proj')

admin.site.register( Employee, EmployeeAdmin )
admin.site.register( Project )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the display name for a field in the model (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#verbose-field-names)

```
class Employee(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
     dob = models.DateField('date of birth')
     doj = models.DateField()
     mobile=models.IntegerField(max_length = 12)
     email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
     bill = models.BooleanField(db_index=True,default=False)
     proj = models.ForeignKey(Project, verbose_name='project')
```

Doing it this way means that all forms for this model (in admin and on the site front-end) will display the text you enter as the field label.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/

```
class Question(models.Model):
    # ...
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'
```

As mentioned here: [How to change Django Admin Custom list field label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141471/how-to-change-django-admin-custom-list-field-label)

Comment: I have added short description also check my edited question. Still its not reflection in admin page. Do i need to add some changes in admin.py also ?